# Does 2D Platformer games still have popularity among gamers?

Tags: unity, 2d, game-design, platformer

I'm currently working on a 2D platformer game that i wanted to put out as my first game but seeing the popularity of other games made by Voodoo and others are quite distressing and made me ask myself this question and now you guys. will the 2D Platformer games that had the popularity will have any popularity for developers to take interest and make some living out of it in the for future projects or can they work on the more popular games like color bump 3d.

Comment: We can not predict the future. But there are a couple 2d platformers which did pretty well in the past couple years. There are of course also hundreds of 2d platformers which did pretty badly, but game development is always a gamble.

Comment: We're not able to speculate about what kinds of games will or will not be popular in the future, nor substitute for market research. It's up to you to study your target player demographics and understand how to serve their needs, how to reach/acquire/engage them, and how to retain them.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its a 2D platformer or not. Gameplay itself is more important. See Terrania, which is the 2D equivalent of Minecraft, or Salt and Sanctuary, which is (somewhat) the 2D equivalent to Dark Souls.

Comment: "Everything that was ever popular is still fun for some people, it's just not fashionable anymore" -- Matthew Colville